# How to print details of image files in the current directory in python

Tags: python

I want to print filename and size, of the image files existing in the current directory. Imagine I have a number of image files in the current directory and I want to have a list like:

```
img1.jpg, 512x256

img2.png, 600x600
```

Do you know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't come with an image-processing library built in, so you're going to have to pick one, install it, and use it. I'll use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) as an example:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for fname in os.listdir():
    try:
        img = Image.open(fname)
    except Exception, e:
        print('{}: could not read: {}'.format(fname, e))
    else:
        print('{}: {}x{}'.format(fname, f.size[0], f.size[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to just get the details of an image file without having install the PIL library. I mean, I don't even want to open any image. In windows when you right click on an image and go to properties/Details you can see all these information

Comment: @user2335132: That's because Windows has an imaging library built in. But unless you want to try to access that library through `ctypes` (or build a custom C extension to expose it to Python), that doesn't do you any good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're literally looking to *print* the image data, there's no reason to write your own code; there are programs that do this.  The one I know of offhand is the `identify` command from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/):

`$ identify -format "%f %[fx:w]x%[fx:h]\n" *
Apollo 11.jpg 900x712
Galaxy (HCG 87).jpg 3291x3291
Galaxy (M106).jpg 1638x1104
Galaxy (NGC 3370).jpg 6031x4456
Pleiades.jpg 1200x827
Saturn and Earth.jpg 2766x1364`